# Understanding this expression and how it relates to what comes after

Tags: expressions, reading-comprehension

I'm a bit confused with this expression 「私も上等じゃない」 as well as how 良く出来てるよ connects to it immediately after. The text in question (apologies if the situation is still vague):

> 屋上から街を眺めながら……世界の終わりを想像するなんて……。
>
> でも……。
>
> ……。
>
> この格好でこんな年頃の少女だったら……まぁ考えてそうかも……。
>
> 世界なんて滅んじゃえばいいのに……とか。とか。
>
> みんな死んじゃえばいいのに……とか。とか。
>
> だから、まぁ……そういった意味じゃ、**私も上等じゃないですか**……。
>
> **良く出来てるよ**……。

I'm aware of the sarcastic use of 上等 that じゃないか often follows with, but I'm not sure if that still applies here as this is all monologue (and not describing someone else's actions). Is the line essentially saying how she fits the bill described (since she's staring down at the city thinking about such morbid things), or how she is perfect in that sense of being morbid, dark? If so, how does 良く出来てる make sense here?

My translations of the last two lines are:

"In that sense, I'm quite the perfect match here, huh?"

"A lot of time was put into my character, you know." <- a strange meta joke?

Comment: Suggest showing your translation attempts for the two phrases specifically mentioned.

Comment: For the first one I interpreted as calling herself first-class, so I guess I mistakenly drew a correlation with it also meaning "be more than a perfect match."
As for the latter, I couldn't find what was being described as well-made in earlier context (besides maybe her hypothetical doomsday story) so I assumed it was directed at herself. Obviously, "I'm well made" feels weird, so I thought it might've been something more abstract.
Of course, this is most likely wrong too.

Comment: I think you're right about 上等 ("fits the bill"), but to be honest I'm not sure how to understand the final sentence... I can't still fully grasp the background. Can you describe the situation? Or what comes after?

Comment: She gets interrupted by someone immediately after the last line, and the background itself is her standing on a rooftop by herself, thinking about how the city she lives in (and the world in general) is seemingly unchanging. The end of the world lines comes from her thinking about some major world change (apocalypse, etc) that would break that "dullness." 
I'm really just lead to believe this is strange phrasing by the writer, as the character says something similar later on in the work: 「そうなんだ……私はわりかし自分好きだよ……良くできてるなぁ……って思う」  (she explains how she personally feels about herself).